# How to manage a jquery object

Tags: jquery

I have the following code:

```
function validarEnviarPatrocinio(){

        var fila = $("#fila").val();

        for(var e=1; e<6; e++){
            $("#email_contactopatrocinador"+e).val($("#email_contactopatrocinador"+e+fila).val());
            var email = $("#email_contactopatrocinador"+e+fila).val();  

            if(validarEmail(email)){

            }
            if(!validarEmail(email)){

            }
        }

 }
```

This object runs through 5 input fields. The problem is that its suppose to validate the fields for correct email addresses.

Here is my issue:

If I fill in the first field correctly and any of the other fields wrong it validates when it shouldnt. It should only validate when the fields are in correct format.

**NOTE:** You should be able to leave fields in blank and if the other fields filled in are correct it should validate.

Answer (score 0):

Try the following.  It breaks out of your loop and you shouldn't be validating the rest.

```
function validarEnviarPatrocinio(){
    var fila = $("#fila").val();

    for(var e=1; e<6; e++){
        $("#email_contactopatrocinador"+e).val($("#email_contactopatrocinador"+e+fila).val());
        var email = $("#email_contactopatrocinador"+e+fila).val();  

        if(validarEmail(email)){

        } else {
            break;
        }
    }
 }
```